# Why does Bane's henchman sacrifice himself?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In the very beginning of the movie (the airplane scene,) when Bane is about to leave the plane with the nuclear scientist, the following dialogue takes place between Bane and one of his men:

> Bane: No, they expect one of us at the wreckage brother.
>
> Man: Have we started the fire?
>
> Bane: Yes, the fire rises.

And then the guy just gives up his parachute and stays behind in the plane. What is this all about? Does Bane have mind-manipulating powers of some sort, or are his men just so loyal that they are willing to kill themselves just because he asks them to nicely? And what about the word "brother"? It reminds me of cult leaders who convince people to just kill themselves so that they can be redeemed. In addition, what is Bane's ethnic background supposed to be in the movie? He clearly has an accent in English.

Comment: [Reference to your last question.](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/what-nationality-is-bane)

Comment: [Also reference to your 1st question.](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/what-type-of-leader-is-bane)

Comment: By the way, tags in titles are discouraged. I cleaned up your titles but just so you know for future questions. Welcome to movies.se.

Comment: So text that makes up a tag can't be used in a title?

Comment: Because, it's [Christmas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChaN2YQqf50). ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is exactly as you say, all of Bane's henchmen are willing to sacrifice themselves for the cause.

Due to Bane essentially taking over the League of Shadows, being a mastermind of his own accord, and having a cause that all his followers believe in, he attracts such skilled zealots and is able to use them as he pleases.

He shows no remorse for this because he believes that all the lives that are given to this cause of wiping Gotham clean will be worth it in the end, and it doesn't matter how much of his men fall, as long as the goal is reached.

So the short answer is **no**, he does not have any powers over one's mind.  Just a cause that they all believe is worthy of their lives.

As far as Bane's nationality, that has already been answered in the comments and on another question.

Comment: Just like terrorist group leader brain-washses his followers.

Answer (score 7):

Its because the police guy at the plane said that only one person was supposed to be at the plane. So bane wanted the guys to stay so that the investigators would believe that the doctor (dead guy with real doctors blood), the police guys and the one person died in a 'accidental' plane crash. Bane did this so they wouldn't know it was a kidnapping and that the doctor was captured.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the accepted answer doesn't include the crucial detail that CIA-man probably wasn't lying when he said "My flight plan includes me, my men, and one of you.  The first one who talks gets to stay on my plane!"  Which makes sense, since the scene opens with CIA-man saying "we didn't expect these others."  The "one of you" bit on the flight plan was for the turncoat informant that Bane was after.  That's why bane says "No, they expect one of us at the wreckage brother."  His body was taking the place of the informant (but also to show what respect Bane had in the organization and what committed zealots the organization was).

Why he wanted the body count to match the flight plan is anyone's guess.  It can't have been for making the plane crash look like an accident, what with the wings and rear of the plane is very unusual places on the ground for a crash.  * shrug *

Comment: Based on how the question is written it seems that OP was interested in why a _random_ henchman agreed so easily to sacrifice his life. The question is not about why staying in the plane was needed.

Answer (score -1):

Bane was in the prison pit and escapes where he joins the League of Shadows. After Bruce kills the leader Bane becomes the leader for the League of Shadows. So in a way Bruce is responsible for the Bane's authority over the league.

I thought it was mentioned in the film, that after his training by the league he returns to the prison pit and frees the prisoners. They all join him as his army to take over Gotham.

The prison pit was created to hold the most notorious criminals and the insane. So their extreme loyalty comes from his history in the prison. Where he was known as the ruthless prisoner who would kill anyone in his way.

Comment: It was never mentioned that *Bane* freed the prisoners from the pit. In the end he used that prison himself to imprison people (and those prisoners don't really look like they've been there for just a couple of years). It is mentioned that *Bane* himself was freed by *Ducard*, but that is unrelated to any freeing of other prisoners *by* him. And in the end their loyality doesn't seem to come from fear either, but rather admiration/inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

To me it actually doesn't make any sense as to why he had to stay on the plane. I understand why he did, but he really didn't have to. First of all those agents did not really call in and say they only had one extra guy picked up. The guys had no intention of killing them, which Bane pointed out. Second, you would think there would have been a better DNA test done on the fake doctor stiff, because all they did was pump him with a small amount of the doctor's blood. Lastly and more importantly, that plane and the bodies in it have bullets and shell casing everywhere, the wings came off, they used explosives to blow off the back end. No investigator would believe that crash was an accident.

Answer (score -1):

'CIA', played by Aiden Gillan, promised Bane's henchmen that "The first one to talk gets to stay on my plan." 'Brother', the hired gun who sacrificed himself was the first one to talk, in spite of having a "lotta loyalty". That's why he stayed on the plane and died in the wreckage.

In the movie it appears that Bane is the first one of the prisoners to talk, saying from beneath his hood "Or perhaps he's wondering why someone would shoot a man, before throwing him out of a plane?" But as Bane was hooded how can we know it was he that spoke? 'Brother' must have impersonated Bane, else Bane would have had to keep Gillan's promise and stay on the plane instead of being hauled away on a rope.